# mmap2 fails to allocate a stack for a thread, but works under GDB

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gdb, arm, mmap

I am running application on ARMv7-A machine with Fedora 18, 2GB of RAM.

The application terminates:

```
130413 15:49:34 19344 Xrd: PhyConnection: Can't run reader thread: out of system resources. Critical error.
```

If I `strace` that, I see that allocation of stack fails for a new thread:

```
mmap2(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
gettimeofday({1365921367, 588018}, NULL) = 0
gettid()                                = 6309
writev(2, [{"130414 02:36:07 6309 ", 21}, {"Xrd", 3}, {"", 0}, {": ", 2}, {"PhyConnection: Can't run reader "..., 80}, {"\n", 1}], 6130414 02:36:07 6309 Xrd: PhyConnection: Can't ru
n reader thread: out of system resources. Critical error.
) = 107
munmap(0x48172000, 292)                 = 0
munmap(0x48225000, 292)                 = 0
```

Actual code:

```
253       if (fReaderthreadhandler[i]->Run(this)) {
254          Error("PhyConnection",
255                "Can't run reader thread: out of system resources. Critical error.");
256 // HELP: what do we do here
257          exit(-1);
258       }
```

The application had 300-350MB in virtual memory size, and ~250MB is resident memory size. High memory limitation is 1.3GB. Virtual address space is not limited:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       1024
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 15870
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

But it does work from GDB! I also looked what limits are reported from GDB and they are the same. Thus GDB does not adjust soft limits, which would be inherited.

Summary:

- I have enough memory to run the application. It even works fine inside GDB.
- It doesn't seem that it hit any of the resource limits.
- Works in GDB, but not outside.

Any hints of what could be wrong here?

Comment: [Fedora 18](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_versions#Fedora_18) is Linux 3.6.10

Comment: Have you tried `ulimit -s unlimited`?  Apparently, **MAP_STACK** shouldn't matter, but that is limited to 8M. This is just a guess.  It seems obvious that `mmap` failed, so I would want to understand why the kernel returned *ENOMEM*.  **GDB** may alter program setup, like the stack.

Comment: There are more limits involved than just you total memory consumption: `ENOMEM No memory is available, or the process's maximum number of mappings would have been exceeded.`

Answer (score 0):

> Works in GDB, but not outside.

One thing that is different "inside GDB" is address layout (randomization).

In order to make debugging easier, GDB disables ASLR by default. You can turn it back on with

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
```

and then run the app several times, and check whether it still reliably works.

> I have enough memory to run the application.

The allocation (mapping) that is failing requests 8MB of *continuous* memory, which you may not have if your address space is fragmented. If you don't actually *need* 8MB of stack (most applications don't), you could get many more threads in by setting `ulimit -s` (or use `setrilimit(RLIMIT_STACK, ...)` from within the application) to a significantly smaller value.